# SQL Server get oldest and youngest

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of people with their birthdates, would like to know the youngest and the oldest person.

I am trying to write this code, but it is not valid. How would I do so?

```
SELECT [CustNo]
      ,[name]
      ,[address]
      ,max([Date of Birth]) and min([Date of Birth]), 
      ,[id]
  FROM [Bharath].[dbo].[Customer]
```

This is the table

[image]

Another code that I am trying to do.

```
 SELECT  CustNo, name, address, DATEDIFF(YEAR, [Date of Birth], GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM bharath.dbo.Customer
INNER JOIN (SELECT min [Date of Birth] y , Max [Date of Birth] z FROM Customer) a
 on a.y=dob 
 or a.z=dob
```

This is the code that is working perfectly with all my needs

```
select [CustNo], [name], [address],datediff(year, [date of birth], getdate()) as age , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date of Birth],105)
from Bharath.dbo.Customer
where [Date of Birth] = (select max([Date of Birth]) from Bharath.dbo.Customer) 
or [Date of Birth] = (select min([Date of Birth]) from Bharath.dbo.Customer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you a listing of the persons having the lowest and highest [Date of Birth]:

```
select [CustNo], [name], [address], [Date of Birth], [id] 
from customer
where [Date of Birth] = (select max([Date of Birth]) from customer) 
or [Date of Birth] = (select min([Date of Birth]) from customer)
```

It won't tell you which is youngest or oldest, but that should be obvious from the [Date of Birth]. If multiple persons share the same [Date of Birth] it will return all.

If you want separate queries for youngest and oldest:

```
-- youngest
select [CustNo], [name], [address], [Date of Birth], [id] 
from customer
where [Date of Birth] = (select max([Date of Birth]) from customer) 

-- oldest
select [CustNo], [name], [address], [Date of Birth], [id] 
from customer
where [Date of Birth] = (select min([Date of Birth]) from customer)
```

To calculate age, imprecise due to lack of handling leap years, you can add this to the select statement:

```
case 
    when month(getdate()) < month([date of birth]) then datediff(year, [date of birth], getdate()) - 1
    when month(getdate()) = month([date of birth]) and day(getdate()) < day([date of birth]) then datediff(year, [date of birth], getdate()) 
    when month(getdate()) >= month([date of birth]) and day(getdate()) >= day([date of birth]) then datediff(year, [date of birth], getdate()) 
end as Age
```

I'm sure there are better/more precise ways of calculating age that a Google search should find.

Comment: Can I know what would be the trick to display the datetime column to this format.. CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date Registered],105 ) and also to get the persons age in a separate column as of today. tks in advance.

Comment: To change the display format for the datetime column just change `[Date of Birth]` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date of Birth],105)` in the select statement. Calculating age can be a bit difficult if you want an exact measure (due to leap years), but for value that is correct most of the time you can do `datediff(year, [date of birth], getdate())`

Comment: Actually, the age calculation won't be correct when [Date of Birth] is after the current date (but in an earlier year as it only compares the year part and thus adds a year too much when birth date is after current date.

Comment: I have added the working code, including the age, and yes agree with you regarding the leap years part and also the problem in your last comment, but in my current situation I can neglect these.

Comment: What if the date was a String instead?

Comment: @WhiteGlove Then it should be converted to the proper type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RANK to get the min and max date of birth with the row

```
WIth CTE as (

  SELECT [CustNo]
      ,[name]
      ,[address]
      ,RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY [Date of Birth] asc) MINDATERANK 
      ,RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY [Date of Birth] desc) MAXDATERANK
      ,[Date of Birth] 
      ,[id]
  FROM [Bharath].[dbo].[Customer]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
Where MINDATERANK = 1 or MAXDATERANK= 1
```

This assumes you want multiple rows if you there's are ties for the min or max birthdates
If you want just one row each for min and max you can use ROW_NUMBER instead of rank.

Comment: I think I need to look at CTE, not sure what is that.. but your solution seems very nice..

Comment: Here's [a link for Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx) from more info